# How to get data series to scale with dates in a line graph?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

I have a graph that I want to combine events that happen on a weekly, monthly, quartly, and yearly basis.

For this there will be more data points for each smaller time grouping, i.e. 4 weekly points per month, 4 monthly points per quarter, etc. However each event is not related and is not stacking. For example Event A happens X times per week; Event B happens Y times per month, etc.

To show you how I currently have data input and the chart output:
[image: data input]
[image: chart output]

So as you can see in the chart output the lines are not scaling with the dates, but rather their static points.

Here is what I *want* it to look like (substititute the purple line for the yellow).
[image: wanted output]

**Is there a way to get my wanted output with the current input organization?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your chart type from Line (which uses categorical values for the horizontal axis) to XY/Scatter (which uses numeric values for the horizontal axis).